# How can I login to the Reddit API in C# using OAuth?

Tags: c#, .net, api, reddit

I'd like this to be done with minimal, simple, and clean code.  A lot of the solutions that come up on Google look really bulky.

I need to be able to do this in C#/.NET Core.  I already have a valid app ID and refresh token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend my library [Reddit.NET](https://github.com/sirkris/Reddit.NET).  It's a free and open source managed library for the Reddit API.  It's targetted to .NET Standard 2.0, which means it is compatible with .NET Core apps.

You can install it via the NuGet Package Manager Console:

`Install-Package Reddit`

Then in your program code, do something like this:

```
using Reddit;

...

var reddit = new RedditAPI("YourRedditAppID", "YourBotUserRefreshToken");

Console.WriteLine("Username: " + reddit.Account.Me.Name);

Console.WriteLine("Cake Day: " + reddit.Account.Me.Created.ToString("D"));
```

That's it!  Reddit.NET was designed to provide easy, simple access to the Reddit API with little to no boilerplate code required.

Note that Account.Me automatically caches so you can access it repeatedly without duplicating the same API call or having to store it in a local variable.